# Categorize a datetime interval based on other datetime interval and put values on columns

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I'm dealing with a hard challenge and I don't know how to solve it.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Product_Name        Start_Time               End_Time
 Product X      2021-10-20 20:32:00     2021-10-21 03:50:00 
 Product Y      2021-10-21 11:50:00     2021-10-21 16:00:00 
 Product Z      2022-01-11 20:10:00     2022-01-12 15:30:00
```

And I have 3 range time and a category for each one:

```
A: 05:01 to 14:00
B: 14:01 to 22:00
C: 22:01 to 05:00
```

What I want to do is calculate how much decimal hours each category (A,B and C) have based on "Start_Time" and "End_Time", reaching some like this:

```
Product_Name        Start_Time               End_Time           A        B       C
 Product X      2021-10-20 20:30:00     2021-10-21 03:50:00    0.00     1.50    5.82
 Product Y      2021-10-21 11:50:00     2021-10-21 16:00:00    2.17     1.98    0.00
 Product Z      2022-01-11 20:10:00     2022-01-12 15:30:00    8.98     3.31    6.98
```

Could you guys help me how to do it?

I'm  a really beginner in python, pandas etc, and when I wrote the post first time I really had no ideia how to even start to code it.
So I start to think in something and I get this code, I'm sure it's not right, but I think it's a start of something:

```
start_a = 05:01:00
end_a = 14:00:00

start_b = 14:01:00
end_b = 22:00:00

start_c = 22:01:00
end_c = 05:00:00



if df['Start_Time'] > start_a and df['End_Time'] < end_a:
    df['A'] = ( df['End_Time'] - start_a ) - ( end_a - df['Start_Time'] )   

else:
    df['A'] = 0


if df['Start_Time'] > start_b and df['End_Time'] < end_b:
    df['B'] = ( df['End_Time'] - start_b ) - ( end_b - df['Start_Time'] )   

else:
    df['B'] = 0


if df['Start_Time'] > start_c and df['End_Time'] < end_c:
    df['C'] = ( df['End_Time'] - start_c ) - ( end_c - df['Start_Time'] )   

else:
    df['C'] = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a lot harder than I thought. One thing that has to be noticed is that the `Start_Time` and `End_Time` can have different dates. Furthermore, category C spans over two days. Both of these facts make the code a little bit complicated, but it seems to work.

First, the setup for your problem. I created your data frame and created the variables. Important is that these structures have the correct data types.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from datetime import datetime, time, date, timedelta

# Create your data frame
data = StringIO("""Product_Name     Start_Time     End_Time
 Product X      2021-10-20 20:32:00     2021-10-21 03:50:00 
 Product Y      2021-10-21 11:50:00     2021-10-21 16:00:00 
 Product Z      2022-01-11 20:10:00     2022-01-12 15:30:00""")
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='     ', engine='python')

# Convert the columns to date time format
df[["Start_Time", "End_Time"]] = df[["Start_Time", "End_Time"]].apply(pd.to_datetime)

# Create the range start and end time as datetime format
start_a = datetime.strptime('05:01:00', '%H:%M:%S')
end_a = datetime.strptime('14:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')
start_b = datetime.strptime('14:01:00', '%H:%M:%S')
end_b = datetime.strptime('22:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')
start_c = datetime.strptime('22:01:00', '%H:%M:%S')
end_c = datetime.strptime('05:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')
```

Then, I created a function that can calculate the hours for your problem. `start` and `end` are the times that are defined for one range. The function now iterates over the days and looks at how much of your range fits in it. Usually, it needs only one iteration, but your `Product Z` goes over two days and needs therefore two iterations.

```
def calc_hours(start_time, end_time, start, end):
    
    # Set range to have date also => allows us to compare to start_time and end_time
    range_start = datetime.combine(start_time.date(), start.time())
    range_end = datetime.combine(start_time.date(), end.time())

    # Special case for range C as end of range is on the next day
    if (range_end<range_start):
        range_end = range_end + timedelta(days=1)

    # start_time and end_time can go over one or more days => Iterate over the days and sum the ours in the range
    total_hours=0.0
    while (range_start < end_time):
        # Calculation to get the hours or zero if range is not within time frame
        hours_in_frame = max((min(range_end, end_time) - max(range_start, start_time)).total_seconds(), 0)/3600
        total_hours += hours_in_frame
        
        # Increment the day to check if range is in time frame
        range_start = range_start + timedelta(days=1)
        range_end = range_end + timedelta(days=1)
    
    return total_hours
```

In order to use the function and add the results to the dataframe, I used the function `apply()` from `pandas`. The `apply()` takes each row of your dataframe and calculates the hours within a range with the previously shown function. This is done for all three ranges.

```
# Use apply to calculate the hours for each row and each range
df['A'] = df.apply(lambda x: calc_hours(x['Start_Time'], x['End_Time'], start_a, end_a), axis=1)
df['B'] = df.apply(lambda x: calc_hours(x['Start_Time'], x['End_Time'], start_b, end_b), axis=1)
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: calc_hours(x['Start_Time'], x['End_Time'], start_c, end_c), axis=1)
```

Output is almost what you wanted, but not rounded to two decimal places:

```
    Product_Name    Start_Time  End_Time    A   B   C
0   Product X   2021-10-20 20:32:00 2021-10-21 03:50:00 0.000000    1.466667    5.816667
1   Product Y   2021-10-21 11:50:00 2021-10-21 16:00:00 2.166667    1.983333    0.000000
2   Product Z   2022-01-11 20:10:00 2022-01-12 15:30:00 8.983333    3.316667    6.983333
```

Comment: I would never do this by myself, I think it's so much advanced for my skill level in python. To be honest, most part of the code I didn't got what you did, could you please recommend me some useful links to learn more about date functions and all the other things you think is mandatory to reach the level to do something like this?

Comment: I'm doing a datacamp data analysis course and I don't think it's something the course will teach me in this level.

Comment: Oh, I was forgetting, thanks so much for your amazing help.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Like most others, I can only tell you that practice will really improve your skills. Practice helps you to get more familiar with the different functions a library like pandas provides. Also, it helps you to divide a problem into easier sub-problems in order to solve a problem systematically. For example, I first programmed the Product X and range A case as it does not require the if and the while loop. From there I expanded the code for the other cases. Unfortunately, I don't know any good sources, but I'm sure you'll find something online.

Comment: Thank you so much again JANO, it was a really challenge to me and I thing I learned a lot with your advices. Thank you man.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to create a Series with all the serial minute numbers of the ranges in question and then intersect them to get the overlapping duration.

Don't have time to provide a full answer but thought I would drop off the idea and you could take it from there.

Create the reference series:

```
start = pd.Timestamp('22:01')
end = pd.Timestamp('05:00')

if end < start: 
    end +=  pd.Timedelta(days=1)

drC = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start=start, end=end, freq='min')).dt.hour * 60 + \
        pd.Series(pd.date_range(start=start, end=end, freq='min')).dt.minute
```

Create a function to do the intersection and duration calculation:

```
def intersecting_duration(x):
    min_of_day = pd.Series(pd.Series(pd.date_range(start=x['Start_Time'], end=x['End_Time'], freq='min')).dt.hour * 60 + \
        pd.Series(pd.date_range(start=x['Start_Time'], end=x['End_Time'], freq='min')).dt.minute)
    
    dur_mins = len(np.intersect1d(min_of_day, drC))       
    return 0 if (dur_mins == 0) else (dur_mins-1)/60
```

Then apply it:

```
df.apply(intersecting_duration, axis=1)

0    5.816667
1    0.000000
2    6.983333
```

You would need to take it from there.